# Map a subtree of YAML to POJO using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I am using Jackson's Object mapper to map a YAML to my Pojo. My YAML is a configuration file and I want to read config of only a particular type using Jackson.

Following is how my YAML looks like:

```
A:
  a:
    1: i
    2: ii
    3: iii

  b:
   foo: bar
```

I want to read all the data lying under `A.a` i.e `1,2,3` in a POJO.

My POJO looks like

```
public class MyPojo{
 String one;
 String two;
 String three;
}
```

You get the idea. I want to map all the children of a particular node in Pojo.

I know I can `readTree("myYaml").get("A").get("a")` and get list of all children. But is there any way already in Jackson to convert that subtree to Pojo just like `readValue(file, class)`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one helped me so I helped my self :).

There is a method `treeToValue(TreeNode, Class)`, so nesting `treeToValue` and `readTree` helps in doing the desired thing.

So in order to read the subtree `A.a`, we need to do

```
File myYamlFile = new File(someclass.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("myYAML").getFile())
MyPojo myPojo = jacksonObjectMapper.treeToValue(jacksonObjectMapper.readTree(myYamlFile).get("A").get("a"), MyPojo.class)
```